Fix AttributeError - Value Counts
df = pd.read_csv('heart-disease.csv')

checking for the value counts in the dataset
# finding out how many of each class there
df["target"].value_counts()

THIS IS THE ERROR AM GETTING
{
    "name": "AttributeError",
    "message": "'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'value_counts'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 2
      1 # Let's find out how many of each class there
----> 2 df["target"].value_counts()

AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'value_counts'"



Please provide a minimal sample DF which produces the error.

This shouldn't happen if df is a pandas dataframe. You must have reassigned df between those two statements.

Welcome to SO! As recommended in [ask], please [edit] your post so as to include a [mre]. We need to be able to reproduce your issue exactly.

I'm assuming you are using the Kaggle Heart Disease Dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/johnsmith88/heart-disease-dataset?resource=download) and this code got me the desired result.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('heart.csv')

print(df['target'].value_counts())

Giving this result:
target
1    526
0    499
Name: count, dtype: int64

As the dtype does not match yours I guess you are not working with this dataset so a sample of yours will be usefull as @user19077881 suggested.
I used the documentation from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html as you might already have judging by your initial code
